# How to mask passwords in logs?

Tags: java, regex, string, servlets

What is the best approach to hide confidental data, e.g. passwords into logs.

I would like to log body of POST requests, which are send to my Servlet. But logging password isn't a good idea. How to mask passwords? If the regular expression is the best idea, can you propose some examples?

```
// Example:
password=123456asedqwe -> password=***
bla&password=qweqweqwe -> bla&password=***
password=qweqweqwe&qwe=qwe -> password=***&qwe=qwe
```

Comment: Like you said, logging passwords is not a good idea at all. Why don't you remove that field from logging?

Comment: I need information that password appeared in request

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can try the following simple regex replacement. It assumes that the password lies between `password=` and the next `&`.

```
    String s = "password=qweqweqwe&qwe=qwe ";
    String maskedPassword = s.replaceAll("password=[^&]*", "password=***");
    System.out.println(maskedPassword);
```

prints:

```
password=***&qwe=qwe
```

Comment: Caution: If the password contains an '&' you might expose the second half of the password.